# While printing, variable adding previous value with the new value in C

Tags: c, for-loop, variable-assignment

I was writing this program to print sum of consecutive odd numbers between two given numbers for a number of test cases. It will first take an **input** for *testcase* and run on loop and then it will take *two numbers X and Y* as **inputs**. The output will be the sum of all odd numbers between X and Y. (Excluding X and Y)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int testcase,sum=0;
    scanf("%d", &testcase);
    for (int i=0; i<testcase; i++)
    {
        int x,y;
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        if (x>y)
        {
            for (int i=y+1; i<=x-1; i++)
            {
                if (i%2!=0)
                {
                    sum=sum+i;
                }
            }
                printf("%d\n", sum);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i=x+1; i<=y-1; i++)
            {
                if (i%2!=0)
                {
                    sum=sum+i;
                }
            }
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

While running the program, the sum variable stores the previous result and adds it with the new result and then prints. This is how the terminal looks -
[Program keeps adding previous value with the new one before printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK74R.png)

Comment: The variable sum shall be reset to 0 in each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text. Program output is text.

Comment: OT: you should remove the code duplication and rather swap the x and y variables if x is larger than y.

Comment: `int testcase, sum=0;` -> `int testcase;` and put `int sum=0;` right after `scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);`. Generally declare and initialize your variables where they are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int testcase;
    scanf("%d", &testcase);
    for (int i=0; i<testcase; i++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        int x,y;
        char * in="Input";
        printf("Input %d \n", i);
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        if (x>y)
        {
            for (int i=y+1; i<=x-1; i++)
            {
                if (i%2!=0)
                {
                    sum=sum+i;
                }
            }
                printf("%d\n", sum);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i=x+1; i<=y-1; i++)
            {
                if (i%2!=0)
                {
                    sum=sum+i;
                }
            }
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Initialise the sum=0 inside the loop.Have to initialise each time you getting input

Answer (score 0):

As Arun has already answered, the OP need to reset `sum` between each case. However, it is also possible to take a different approach to calculating the sum. I will focus on that.

This is a case where a little math can improve performance. If the difference between `y` and `x` is large, then the program has to iterate many times to calculate the result.

We can, in fact, derive an explicit formula. Assume that `x<y` (the case `x>y` is symmetric, i.e. just replace `x` with `y` and `y` with `x`).

First, make the endpoints even without changing the sum:

```
  x2 = (x+1) & ~1;  // Round up to nearest even number
  y2 = y & ~1;      // Round down to nearest even number
```

Then calculate the number of odd integers between (and excluding) the endpoints:

```
  n = (y2-x2) / 2;
```

Now, notice that the sum is:

> (x2+1) + (x2+3) + ... + (x2 + (2*n-1)) =
>
> n * x2 + (1 + 3 + ... + (2*n-1)) =
>
> n * x2 + n * n =
>
> n * (x2 + n)

(this uses the fact that the sum of the first n odd integers is n^2)

Hence, the result is:

```
   sum = n * (x2 + n);
```

Comment: What does "&" and "~" do in " x2 = (x+1) & ~1" and "y2 = y & ~1" ?
and how does x2 and y2 stores only even numbers by using  "&" and "~" ?

Comment: I tried to apply the algorithm provided by nielsen but I think I have made some mistake while implementing in code. I submitted the code on codeforces (https://codeforces.com/group/MWSDmqGsZm/contest/219432/problem/S) and it shows "Wrong Answer on Test 2".

Comment: @Didar004 (1) The part "& ~1" clears the lowest bit. An integer is even if and only if the lowest bit in binary representation is 0.
(2) As stated, the formula assumes that x<y. Hence, if y>x, then x and y needs to be swapped. Maybe your implementation missed that?

Comment: thank you, I really missed that but now now it shows "Wrong Answer on Test 5"  :)

Comment: @Arun yours was accepted thankfully but unfortunately not with nielsen 's algorithm.

Comment: You just asked what was the mistake. I answered that,you haven't asked for better alogorithm in question :(